# What are "tid" and "len" in Visual Force Remoting actions?

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, performance, salesforce1-platform

I have no knowledge of the SalesForce1 platform, but am required to performance test a few UI pages/endpoints of a customer applications using a JMeter script.

SO far I have been able to invoke most methods on Controllers, however there are a few which are not working.

I am stuck at the point where I have to provide a valid "tid" on one of the requests. When I look at the request (lets say Validate an item) using a browser's developer console, I see that the TID changes as requests progress (sometimes increments by 1, other times by 2 and so.on). Using a static TID in my jmeter http-sampler is not helping and causes 400 errors.

I did some googling around, but could not get to a definitive answer. What is the TID, what value should I set in order to make a direct HTTP request, how do I emulate changing TID's in my Jmeter scripts, or is there a way to bypass this issue altogether (maybe some setup configuration etc..)

Apologies, I donot know what specific information to provide as I am new to this technology. Let me know if you need anything specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Precaution:**
>
> It is nowhere documented. You will not get any offcial detail about
>   these arguments. Salesforce uses them for internal request maintenance.
>   Below is my understamding as per my experience:-

TID is the transaction ID. Each remoting function execution result has unique transaction ID. It is always incremented by 1. If you see it incremented by 2, you have probably missed a request in between. Data type is Integer.

LEN is the number of arguments passed in remoting function. It is not necessary the this property will always received as part of call.

Comment: What you said about TID maybe right, but LEN seems wrong. It maybe the number of parameters being passed to the remoting function,

Comment: @smantripragada Yes, LEN is the number of arguments, not the size of response.